# Excel error saves temp files but I can't find them.

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I saved my work in an existing Excel 2000 document on an external hard drive using Windows 7 I got this message in a Microsoft Excel window:
Your changes could not be saved to 'document6.xls', but were saved to a temporary document named '41FE8200'. Close the existing document, then open the temporary document and save it under a new name.

Not a huge deal for this document but it happened on another document this morning and then deleted the original document on the second pass of this message and I lost 4 years worth of updates.

I NEED to find that temp document and have run searches with no hidden files checked and searched every possible path.

Where might it be??

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer may be to check the following places:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft
```

or

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp
```

These files may not have the name you gave them, but rather a temp file assigned by Excel, usually with a `.tmp` extension.

Comment: In addition to that you might want to look at the timestamps to narrow it down

Comment: Excel did give it a temp name as in the excel message in the thread. "41FE8200" but it is not in any file I have searched or located with a search of my computer